# Is fermentation another word for excitement?

Tags: meaning

My grandma phoned me recently for some help with a crossword.  The clue was 'excitement', we had a few letters but couldn't think of anything.

Anyway the answers came out and she rang me back a little put out that the answer was 'fermentation'.

She has looked up in several dictionaries and doesn't feel that the clue is suitable for the answer.  I can maybe see it from a chemical sort of viewpoint with fermentation involving bubbling, frothing etc.  So is this a suitable clue?  Is there a definition of fermentation that could mean excitement?  Or the other way round?

Comment: Well, to *excite* a mixture would be to cause it to make bubbles, but I don't believe that that's close enough to *fermentation*. For example, if I let something *ferment*, I'm probably leaving it alone for a long time. If it's bubbling, I'm not *exciting* it, but a chemist might say that it is being *excited*. I'm not too sure, though, either way.

Comment: @waiwai fermentation is less likely an antonym of excitement is it?  and thats not usually how crosswords work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As reported by the NOAD, *fermentation* has also the archaic meaning of *agitation, excitement*.

> I had found Paris in high fermentation.

Answer (score 3):

This is an occasionally used meaning of fermentation, but the meaning is more commonly encountered in the form *ferment*, as in

> Egypt has recently been in ferment

Crossword clues are notorious for being obscure; this is one of the sources of frustration with these puzzles.

Answer (score 1):

I can sort of see it as a possibility based on some figurative uses of the word, such as "a period of social fermentation" when ideas and changes are bubbling about in the community, but unless someone posts a really great answer explaining it a lot better, I'm inclined to agree that it's a poor clue.